# The app pool looses its identity

Tags: application-pool

I am running into a very weird issue, every morning around 8:55 AM one of our SharePoint App Pool looses its identity. Its been happening fore more than a week now.

This app pool holds 12 applications, including Serach, Managed Metadata and User Profile.

This app pool is running in farm's identity, couple of weeks back we had changed the password of the farm but after that everything was working fine.

Then in last one week somehow the app pool started loosing its credentials at around 8:55 AM and eventually stoping the app pool. We change the password and everything starts working fine.

I checked everywhere, there isnt any automated task, which may be be changing it.
Checked the user login/logoff entries in security events but didnt find any thing suspicious.

The app pool configuration 
Idle Timeout:0

Recycling: All parameter set for app pool recyle in case if any thing changes in the configuration.

Load User Profile: false

I have checked the event logs and IIS logs for any clue but nothing has helped so far.

Looking for some pointers, any help is much appreciated.

It's been more than 3 days I have been hitting my head against wall for this problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Today, we again had an outage today but this time I had my enabled the logging and was checking the password in metabase repeatedly. To my surprise the password never changed but the app pool was stopped. Engaged networks and found that the user was in  locked state.

Some other process from some other server was impersonating this user with old password, which was causing multiple login failure and eventually locking the user. Then a group policy was unlocking this account after a short interval, which was causing the subsequent app pool  restart successful.

Thanks everybody for help!